# exiting from php command without triggering shutdown functions

Tags: php, callback, exit, abort, atexit

how can I exit from a php script (for example with the exit() function) but without triggering all previously registered shutdown functions (with register_shutdown_function)?

Thanks!

EDIT: alternatively, is there a way to clear from all the registered shutdown functions?

Comment: Ensure that the first registered shutdown function contains a path that calls exit()

Comment: I am working with a very complex system, and I don't actually know which is the first registered shutdown function. I just would like to exit without calling the shutdown functions, so I can debug easily.

Comment: If you want to debug easily, use a debugger (like xdebug) where you can set breakpoints and inspect values, etc

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Shutdown functions will not be executed if the process is killed with a SIGTERM or SIGKILL signal.

```
posix_kill(posix_getpid(), SIGTERM);
```

Answer (score 4):

Don't use register_shutdown_function directly. Create a class which manage all shutdown functions and which has his own function and an enable property.

```
class Shutdown {

    private static $instance = false;
    private $functions;
    private $enabled = true;

    private function Shutdown() {
        register_shutdown_function(array($this, 'onShutdown'));
        $this->functions = array();
    }

    public static function instance() {
        if (self::$instance == false) {
            self::$instance = new self();
        }

        return self::$instance;
    }

    public function onShutdown() {
        if (!$this->enabled) {
            return;
        }

        foreach ($this->functions as $fnc) {
            $fnc();
        }
    }

    public function setEnabled($value) {
        $this->enabled = (bool)$value;
    }

    public function getEnabled() {
        return $this->enabled;
    }

    public function registerFunction(callable $fnc) {
        $this->functions[] = $fnc;
    }

}
```